# PhoneGap + Childbrowser + Error

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, childbrowser

I am trying to use the Childbrowser plugin in my application. My code is as follows:

```
ChildBrowser.prototype.showWebPage = function(url, options) {
    options = options || {
        showLocationBar: true,
        locationBarAlign: "top"
    };
    //Code Runs up to this point
    cordova.exec(this._onEvent, this._onError, "ChildBrowser", "showWebPage", [url, options]);
};
```

The last line of the code does nothing. It's not giving any errors, but the webpage is not shown. I am using Android 2.3.

Comment: Same here. It does work just fine under 4.x though.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be defining this wrongly, I think it should look like this:

```
var url = "http://www.google.com";

window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage( url, {showLocationBar: true});// This opens the webpage.
```

I do not quite get why you have used the `ChildBrowser.prototype.showWebPage`